# Python Class - required positional Argument

Tags: python-3.x

I am a bit confused what exactly is wrong in here. I've seen plenty of questions about below error but still can't find the right answer for my code. I am just starting with classes in Python and I wanted to decode a bit ( I got 5 different functions for different type of API data).

```
class Weather:

    def __init__(self, R):
        self.R = R = requests.get(
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "," + COUNTRY + "&appid=xxx")

    def temp(self):
        """Temp function with conversion to C degree"""

        JSON_OBJECT = self.R.json()
        TEMP_K = (JSON_OBJECT["main"]["temp"])
        TEMP_C = TEMP_K - 273.15
        return (TEMP_C)
```

Idea is to put those 2 into "variables" to avoid repetition:

```
requests.get(
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "," + COUNTRY + "&appid=xxx")
JSON_OBJECT = self.R.json()
```

My error looks like that:

```
TypeError: temp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This is the line where error appears:

```
print("Current tempreture in {} is: {} C.".format(CITY, Weather.temp()))
```

Comment: Hint: you forgot to actually create an instance of the `Weather` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `temp` as a *method* of the `Weather` class.

That means you should call it from an *instance* of the `Weather` class.

---

In this case, I would suggest not using a class at all.

A general piece of Python [wisdom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) states that if you have a class with two methods, one of which is `__init__`, then you basically have a function. So use a function:

```
import requests

def get_weather_json(city, country):
    R = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "," + country + "&appid=xxx")
    return R.json()
```

Comment: To be honest i lack with the idea how to start- In general i know what the instance is but is making me so confused. I am obviously not asking for explaining how instance work, since there are tons of info all over the internet but I just can't put that knowledge into this example

Comment: The thing is, it's just a piece of code. I got 6 different functions when i referee to API code, that's why I used class here

Comment: Your weather class just calls an API when it is instantiated. If it is meant to do that, *it's just a function in disguise*. If you want to save and re-use the results of the API call, then you can just save the result of `get_weather_json`.

Comment: Is that a bad manner to cover several funcions into a class to group them? I think i know the proper idea of useage of Classes ( like list of employees etc) but its still rather unknown subject and i wanted to push Classes to this code to train them in any way

Comment: Classes are a good fit for some things (like GUI toolkits), but not always. Don't fall in to the "everything must be a class" trap. I call that the Java Disease. If you ever have trouble fitting a solution into a class, that's a good sign you're doing it wrong. :-) Sometimes I do miss plain old C `struct` in Python, but [there are ways to achieve that](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/programming/structures-in-python.html).

Comment: So I guess I am gonna remove the class and group functions in a different way. Now I need to write another app with Classes to learn them in a proper way :) If You've any ideas - I'd appriciate them!